# Crontab running python script every minute instead of every two hour

Tags: python, linux, unix, cron

I tried to execute crontab every 2 hour, but the script is getting executed every minute.

I used: `* */2 * * * <path/to/python> <python_script>`

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you explain how you reached the conclusion that the `* */2 * * *` pattern should execute every 2 hours, and not every 2 minutes…? What research have you done, maybe using [contab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#*_*/2_*_*_*) or similar, to try and work this out on your own before posting here (in accordance with [ask])?

Comment: You wrote: every minute of every 2nd hour. Change the first * to a fixed value.

Comment: first `*` matches to every minut - you have to use ie. `0` to run it at `2:00`, `4:00`, etc. or `1` to run it at `2:01`, `4:01`, etc. or any other value `0` to `59`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to execute crontab every 2 hours, use this.

```
0 */2 * * *
```

it run at minute 0 past every 2nd hour.